# REGEX_SUBSTR - Match the second occurrence of one or two digits

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to extract the digit(s) after the second underscore in the below example, my regex matches the string only if has two digits (17 for example) but doesn't match it when it is single digit. I wonder what did I miss?

> trim(LEADING '0' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR( mystr, '*(\d{2,})**', 1, 1, 'i',
>   1 )))

- Matched string str_0_17_1 -> 17 is matched
- Non matched string str_0_1_3 -> 1 is not matched

Answer (score 1):

You regex matches two or more consecutive digits regardless of where they some in the string. This means that it will extract `12` from the string `str_123_1_3`, which is not what you I believe.

Change you regex to match any digit sequence (`\d+`) and tell `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to return the second occurrence of the regex by passing `2` in the fourth parameter:

```
trim(LEADING '0' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR( mystr, '\d+', 1, 2, 'i')))
```

Note the last parameter is not required since the match itself contains the number you need.

By the way, you may simplify the whole expression by eliminating `trim`. You may extract all digits excluding potential leading zeros using a regex with a capture group:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( mystr, '0*(\d+)', 1, 2, 'i', 1)
```

Here you need the last parameter to return the captured group only.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('str_0_0123_3', '_[^_]*_0*([0-9]+)_', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as result from dual
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/EQWCG27985)

**Details**:

- `_`  - underscore
- `[^_]*` - zero or more chars other than underscore
- `_` - underscore
- `0*`  - zero or more `0`s
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `_` - an underscore

The last `1` argument means only the capture group contents is returned.

No need to use `i` modifier since there are no letters in the pattern.